# Rails 3 has_many changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

I need to track changes (additions and deletes) of an association set up like this:

```
has_many :listing_services
has_many :services, through: :listing_services
```

For normal attributes the easist way to do it is to check `l.changes[attribute]` in `before_save` or `l.previous_changes[attribute]` in `after_save`.

The question is, what is the best way to do it for `has_many` attributes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I didn't use `changes` method. But I'm sure that you always can use magic methods `<attribute_name>_changed?` and `<attribute_name>_was`:

```
services.any? {|s| s.attribute_name_changed?}
services.map(&:attribute_name_was)
```

See Ryan Bates's railscast for more information: [#109 episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/109-tracking-attribute-changes)

**UPDATE**: You can pass `:after_delete`, and `:after_add` callbacks to `has_many` association directly:

```
has_many :items, :after_add => :my_method_or_proc1, :after_remove => :my_method_or_proc2
```

**Be careful using these callbacks and pay attention how they work.** They
are called on `items.build` and `items.create` *once*. So if you call
`items.build` and then save parent object (with nested attributes for
example) `after_add` callback *will be called only once on building
associated object*. It means that if parent has validation then built `items` won't be saved in the database and you can't rely on `after_add` callback. In other words it doesn't say that added association's record was saved in the DB. So you have guarantee that item is added and saved only on call `items.create`. I hope you understand this clarification.

Comment: For me this only works, if the associated object is updated. It does NOT work for me, if the associated object is added or removed (since then it is no longer present in the `services` association). What am I doing wrong?